# Anaconda Package Installation OSError(22, 'The parameter is incorrect', None, 87, None)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I am having problems with Anaconda, installing some packages. I have installed Anaconda and am having a problem installing packages. Anytime I try using the install buttons on the Anaconda distributions for packages (glueviz, orange3 and veusz), and it goes through the install process, but the install button is still available, not the launch.

This is for Anaconda3-5.3.1-Windows-x86_64

Trying to install using the conda prompt using:
conda install -c conda-forge glueviz

or the equivalent leads to the following error teach time:

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while
>   installing package 'conda-forge::pyopengl-3.1.1a1-py_1'. OSError(22,
>   'The parameter is incorrect', None, 87, None) Attempting to roll back.
>
> Rolling back transaction: done
>
> OSError(22, 'The parameter is incorrect', None, 87, None)

This happens regardless of the package I am trying to install.

The entire transaction is listed below:

> (base) C:\Users\Tom>conda install -c conda-forge glueviz
>
> Solving environment: done
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs:
>       - glueviz
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> conda-4.5.11               |        py37_1000         654 KB  conda-forge
> certifi-2018.11.29         |        py37_1000         144 KB  conda-forge
> snappy-1.1.7               |           vc14_1          80 KB  conda-forge
> bzip2-1.0.6                |           vc14_1         144 KB  conda-forge
> glueviz-0.14.0             |                0          17 KB  conda-forge
> curl-7.60.0                |           vc14_0         367 KB  conda-forge
> libxslt-1.1.32             |           vc14_0         456 KB  conda-forge
> glue-vispy-viewers-0.11    |             py_0         612 KB  conda-forge
> glue-core-0.14.0           |           py37_0         1.5 MB  conda-forge
> fast-histogram-0.5         |py37h452e1ab_1001          23 KB  conda-forge
> dask-0.19.1                |             py_0           3 KB  conda-forge
> openssl-1.0.2p             |    hfa6e2cd_1001         5.4 MB  conda-forge
> sqlite-3.22.0              |           vc14_0         907 KB  conda-forge
> lzo-2.10                   |           vc14_0         154 KB  conda-forge
> krb5-1.14.6                |           vc14_0         767 KB  conda-forge
> mpl-scatter-density-0.4    |             py_0         1.6 MB  conda-forge
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                        Total:        12.7 MB
> ```
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> ```
> dill:                0.2.8.2-py37_1000     conda-forge
> fast-histogram:      0.5-py37h452e1ab_1001 conda-forge
> glue-core:           0.14.0-py37_0         conda-forge
> glue-vispy-viewers:  0.11-py_0             conda-forge
> glueviz:             0.14.0-0              conda-forge
> krb5:                1.14.6-vc14_0         conda-forge [vc14]
> mpl-scatter-density: 0.4-py_0              conda-forge
> plotly:              3.4.2-py_0            conda-forge
> pyopengl:            3.1.1a1-py_1          conda-forge
> pyreadline:          2.1-py37_1000         conda-forge
> retrying:            1.3.3-py_2            conda-forge
> ```
>
> The following packages will be UPDATED:
>
> ```
> astropy:             3.0.4-py37hfa6e2cd_0              --> 3.1-py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
> bokeh:               0.13.0-py37_0                     --> 1.0.2-py37_1000          conda-forge
> bottleneck:          1.2.1-py37h452e1ab_1              --> 1.2.1-py37h452e1ab_1001  conda-forge
> ca-certificates:     2018.03.07-0                      --> 2018.11.29-ha4d7672_0    conda-forge
> certifi:             2018.8.24-py37_1                  --> 2018.11.29-py37_1000     conda-forge
> conda:               4.5.11-py37_0                     --> 4.5.11-py37_1000         conda-forge
> dask:                0.19.1-py37_0                     --> 0.19.1-py_0              conda-forge
> h5py:                2.8.0-py37h3bdd7fb_2              --> 2.8.0-py37h54c06b0_1003  conda-forge
> imageio:             2.4.1-py37_0                      --> 2.4.1-py37_1000          conda-forge
> jpeg:                9b-hb83a4c4_2                     --> 9b-vc14_2                conda-forge [vc14]
> libpng:              1.6.34-h79bbb47_0                 --> 1.6.34-vc14_0            conda-forge [vc14]
> libsodium:           1.0.16-h9d3ae62_0                 --> 1.0.16-vc14_0            conda-forge [vc14]
> libxslt:             1.1.32-hf6f1972_0                 --> 1.1.32-vc14_0            conda-forge [vc14]
> matplotlib:          2.2.3-py37hd159220_0              --> 2.2.3-py37h31860fd_0     conda-forge
> mkl_fft:             1.0.4-py37h1e22a9b_1              --> 1.0.6-py37hdbbee80_0
> numpy:               1.15.1-py37ha559c80_0             --> 1.15.4-py37ha559c80_0
> numpy-base:          1.15.1-py37h8128ebf_0             --> 1.15.4-py37h8128ebf_0
> openssl:             1.0.2p-hfa6e2cd_0                 --> 1.0.2p-hfa6e2cd_1001     conda-forge
> pandas:              0.23.4-py37h830ac7b_0             --> 0.23.4-py37h830ac7b_1000 conda-forge
> pytest-arraydiff:    0.2-py37h39e3cac_0                --> 0.3-py_0                 conda-forge
> pytest-astropy:      0.4.0-py37_0                      --> 0.4.0-py_0               conda-forge
> pytest-doctestplus:  0.1.3-py37_0                      --> 0.1.3-py_0               conda-forge
> pywavelets:          1.0.0-py37h452e1ab_0              --> 1.0.1-py37h452e1ab_1000  conda-forge
> qtconsole:           4.4.1-py37_0                      --> 4.4.3-py_0               conda-forge
> scikit-image:        0.14.0-py37h6538335_1             --> 0.14.1-py37h6538335_1001 conda-forge
> tk:                  8.6.8-hfa6e2cd_0                  --> 8.6.8-vc14_0             conda-forge [vc14]
> zeromq:              4.2.5-he025d50_1                  --> 4.2.5-vc14_2             conda-forge [vc14]
> ```
>
> The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
>
> ```
> bzip2:               1.0.6-hfa6e2cd_5                  --> 1.0.6-vc14_1             conda-forge [vc14]
> curl:                7.61.0-h7602738_0                 --> 7.60.0-vc14_0            conda-forge [vc14]
> hdf5:                1.10.2-hac2f561_1                 --> 1.10.2-vc14_0            conda-forge [vc14]
> icu:                 58.2-ha66f8fd_1                   --> 58.2-vc14_0              conda-forge [vc14]
> lzo:                 2.10-h6df0209_2                   --> 2.10-vc14_0              conda-forge [vc14]
> mkl:                 2019.0-118                        --> 2018.0.3-1
> pyqt:                5.9.2-py37h6538335_2              --> 5.6.0-py37h764d66f_1007  conda-forge
> qt:                  5.9.6-vc14h1e9a669_2              --> 5.6.2-vc14_1             conda-forge [vc14]
> sip:                 4.19.8-py37h6538335_0             --> 4.18.1-py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
> snappy:              1.1.7-h777316e_3                  --> 1.1.7-vc14_1             conda-forge [vc14]
> sqlite:              3.24.0-h7602738_0                 --> 3.22.0-vc14_0            conda-forge [vc14]
> vc:                  14.1-h0510ff6_4                   --> 14-0                     conda-forge
> yaml:                0.1.7-hc54c509_2                  --> 0.1.7-vc14_0             conda-forge [vc14]
> zlib:                1.2.11-h8395fce_2                 --> 1.2.11-vc14_0            conda-forge [vc14]
> ```
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages conda-4.5.11         | 654 KB    |
>
> ###################################################################### | 100% certifi-2018.11.29   | 144 KB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% snappy-1.1.7         | 80 KB     |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% bzip2-1.0.6          | 144 KB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% glueviz-0.14.0       | 17 KB     |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% curl-7.60.0          | 367 KB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% libxslt-1.1.32       | 456 KB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% glue-vispy-viewers-0 | 612 KB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% glue-core-0.14.0     | 1.5 MB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% fast-histogram-0.5   | 23 KB     |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% dask-0.19.1          | 3 KB      |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% openssl-1.0.2p       | 5.4 MB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% sqlite-3.22.0        | 907 KB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% lzo-2.10             | 154 KB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% krb5-1.14.6          | 767 KB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% mpl-scatter-density- | 1.6 MB    |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done
>
> Executing transaction: failed ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An
>   error occurred while installing package
>   'conda-forge::pyopengl-3.1.1a1-py_1'. OSError(22, 'The parameter is
>   incorrect', None, 87, None) Attempting to roll back.
>
> Rolling back transaction: done
>
> OSError(22, 'The parameter is incorrect', None, 87, None)

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda 3 times and deleted residual files without avail.

Comment: Can you try `conda install conda-forge::glueviz`?

Comment: Thanks @darthbith, I still get the following error:                                    
`Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::pyopengl-3.1.1a1-py_1'.
OSError(22, 'The parameter is incorrect', None, 87, None)
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

OSError(22, 'The parameter is incorrect', None, 87, None)`

Comment: Are you trying to install these packages into your root environment? Try creating a new one e.g. `conda create -n myenv glueviz`.

Comment: Hi @nekomatic, I am trying to install into those environments, but still without avail. Regardless of different packages, I get the same problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem while creating a virtual environment from a .yml file.

Initially I ran the command from the anaconda prompt, which resulted in the error.

Then I switched to the normal windows command prompt (cmd), which also resulted in the error.

Finally I opened a windows command prompt **as administator**, executed the same command and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling (I had 2x anaconda and 1x miniconda) and re-installing anaconda. I think I had a few conflicts which even stopped me from updating conda.